# When does the function $F(x)=\frac{\operatorname{li}(x^{1/2})}{\operatorname{li}(x)-\pi(x)}$ reach $F(x) > 8$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function

We know [from Ramanujan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637020/on-a-constant-defined-by-ramanujan?rq=1) and Riemann that,

$$\pi(x) = \operatorname{li}(x) -\tfrac12\operatorname{li}(x^{1/2})-\tfrac13\operatorname{li}(x^{1/3})-\tfrac15\operatorname{li}(x^{1/5}) +\dots$$

with prime counting function $\pi(x)$ and logarithmic integral $\operatorname{li}(x)$. I was wondering if we truncate the $\text{RHS}$ up to the *second term* and consider the function,

$$F(x)=\frac{\operatorname{li}(x^{1/2})}{\operatorname{li}(x)-\pi(x)}$$

It turns out it has an interesting plot that peaks and dips *excruciatingly slow*. The plot below shows **the first $10^7$ positive integer $x$** with the vertical axis as $F(x)$. When $x=\text{Skewes' number}$, of course it dips into a negative value,

$\hskip1.8in$[image]

It reaches $F(x)>3$ first at $x_3 = 59753$,

$\hskip1.8in$[image]

$F(x)>4$ at $x_4 = 30902129$,

$\hskip1.8in$[image]

$F(x)>5$ at $x_5 = 110087953 \approx 1.1\times10^{8}$,

$\hskip1.8in$[image]

From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610989/skewes-number-and-the-smallest-x-such-that-pix-operatornamelix), we find 
$$x_6 = 330946474073 \approx 3.3\times10^{11}\\
x_7 \overset{\color{red}?}{=} 1324783721133846733 \approx 1.3\times10^{18}$$

**Note:** It seems there is a large jump to $x_7$, so I'm curious how high we have to go find $F(x) > 8$.

---

> **Q:** Given $F(x) > n$, is there an asymptotic estimate for a bound $B_n$ such that the first $x_n>B_n$?

**P.S.** Some relevant literature may be [*The impact of ζ(s) complex zeros on π(x) for $x<10^{ 10^{ 13}}$*](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2011-80-276/S0025-5718-2011-02477-4/S0025-5718-2011-02477-4.pdf).