# Skewes' number and the ratio $\frac{\operatorname{li}(x^{1/2})}{\operatorname{li}(x)-\pi(x)}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function

(*A complementary post [is here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291164/when-does-the-function-fx-frac-operatornamelix1-2-operatornameli)*.)

Given the *prime counting function* $\pi(x)$ and the *logarithmic integral* $\operatorname{li}(x)$, we have [Table 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function),

$$\begin{array}{|c|l|}
\hline
x&\operatorname{li}(x)-\pi(x)\\
\hline
10^{5}& 38\\
10^{10}& 3104\\
10^{15}& 1052619\\
10^{20}&  222744644\\
10^{25}& 55160980939\\
\hline\end{array}$$
It seems the table suggests $\operatorname{li}(x)-\pi(x)>0$. Amazingly, it actually *[becomes negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27s_number)* near $x=1.397\times10^{316}$ and infinitely many others. If we define an alternative function,

$$F(x)=\frac{\operatorname{li}(x^{1/2})}{\operatorname{li}(x)-\pi(x)}$$

and plot the first $10^7$ positive integer $x$ with $F(x)$ as the vertical axis,

$\hskip1.8in$[image]

It *very* slowly peaks and dips, but the dips now suggest it *might* become negative. The visual trend is no guarantee, but together with Littlewood's result, it may make it easier to see how an entry in Table 1 can become negative.

> **Q1:** Prior to Skewes' number, at what points $x>10^6$ does $F(x)$ dip extremely?

We compute the $F(x)$ for Table 2 of [*The impact of ζ(s) complex zeros on π(x) for $x<10^{ 10^{ 13}}$*](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2011-80-276/S0025-5718-2011-02477-4/S0025-5718-2011-02477-4.pdf),

$$\begin{array}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
x&\approx(x)&F(x)&V(x)\\
\hline
36917098& 3\times10^{7} &1.16&+0.60\\
11467849446& 1\times10^{10} &1.19&+0.63\\
110486344210& 1\times10^{11} &1.18&+0.66\\
36219717668608&  3\times10^{13} &1.12&+0.77\\
1212562524413152& 1\times10^{15} &1.15&+0.72\\
266175790131587542& 2\times10^{17} &1.16&+0.71\\
5.550 \times10^{19}& 5\times10^{19} &?&+0.73\\
\hline\end{array}$$

These are ***all*** seven $x<10^{20}$ with positive $V(x)$, a rather complicated function defined in the paper. At this "small" range, it doesn't even go $<1.1$ yet. However, in Table 3, there are outliers,

$$\begin{array}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
x&\approx(x)&F(x)&V(x)\\
\hline
2.0896\times10^{31} & 2\times10^{31} &?&+0.85\\
1.9098\times10^{215}& 1\times10^{215} &?&+0.999\\
2.5677\times10^{807}& 2\times10^{807} &?&+1.043\\
\hline\end{array}$$

though *Mathematica* can't compute $\pi(x)$ for these.

> **Q2:** Can negative $F(x)$ have positive $V(x)$? (The aforementioned $x=1.397\times10^{316}$ has *negative* $V(x)$, namely $V(x) = -1.000$.)

---

*Appendix:* Tags are the equation numbers in the paper.

$$V(x) = \frac{Z(x)}{R(x)}$$

$$R(x) = \sum_{n=2}^T\frac{-\mu(n)}{n}\,\operatorname{li}\big(x^{1/n}\big)\tag2$$

$$Z(x) = \sum_n\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\sum_{\rho^k} \operatorname{li}\big(x^{\rho_k/n}\big)\tag8$$

with complex zeros $\rho_k$ of $\zeta(s)$, and $T$ is the summation upper limit.